# PHP urlencode differences between versions

Tags: php

When I use `urlencode()` on the same string containing special characters in PHP7 and PHP 5.3.10, the results are different.

### What I tried:

```
urlencode('Testör')
```

Output in PHP7: `Test%C3%B6r`

Output in PHP 5.3: `Test%25C3%25B6r`

Could someone explain what the %25 leading in the older PHP version is?

Comment: [Cannot replicate](https://3v4l.org/3Pjfu)

Comment: @iainn I should have tested the actual result. Sorry for this. The question have been over simplified to be wrong. The actual differences seem to be in the handling of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that you've URL encoded it twice in the 5.3 output. %25 stands for %. Which is missing around the C3.

Comment: This could be the case. Actually I tried to use this within the url of a curl request. I used the same URL in  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url)` and then `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL)` to see the differences with the same input string :/

Comment: What are the results?

Comment: I get these two results of PHP7 and PHP5.3 with the same code: `http://192.168.1.1/update?name=file.zip&title=Test%C3%B6r` 
`http://192.168.1.1/update?name=file.zip&title=Test%25C3%25B6r` I guess there are difference in the url handling of curl

Comment: I will check your answer as correct, as it is the correct answer... still have to research this odd default encoding ...